# getJSON always returns the same data

Tags: jquery, json, api, getjson

Is there a way to refresh the data from `getJSON()`? I want to retrieve a random image URL from an API (and set css background-image). The problem is that the image URL keeps being the same, while it should refresh everytime I call the function.

```
function changeImage() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=336b527b2e18d045045820b78062b95c825376311326b2a08f9b93eef7efc07b", function(result) {
        randomPhoto = result.urls.full;
        console.log(randomPhoto);
    });
};

changeImage();
```

jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/h2jscr46/

Comment: intuitively i'd try appending random number parameter, or even better timestamp like https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=3...07b&forceReload=<some random number>

Comment: I am getting different results every time I run the example in your JS fiddle...? That said, try adding a timestamp to the URL or using `$.ajax` and set `cache: false`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's probably because on running fiddle iframe contents are reloaded

Comment: @entio nope, even on button click without refresh it's a different image URL each time: https://jsfiddle.net/h2jscr46/2/

Comment: if you declare a static url so how it could be change???

Comment: @SatishSam that's not a static url, read about unsplash API.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I bet You have Your developer tools open. Have You disabled "disable cache"? When You do, it loads cached result.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively i'd try appending random number parameter, or even better timestamp like
Try this one:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=3...7b&ts=" + (new Date().getTime())
```

https://jsfiddle.net/entio/L8rphtno/

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the input everyone! I used this eventually:

It was the caching.

```
var randomPhoto = {};

    function changeImage() {

    $.ajax({
  url: "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=336b527b2e18d045045820b78062b95c825376311326b2a08f9b93eef7efc07b",
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
    randomPhoto = result.urls.full;
     console.log(randomPhoto);
  }

});

};

    changeImage();
```

Here is the JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9xft1orw/1/

The API has a rate limit by the way while it is still in development mode

Answer (score 0):

Try using AJAX for refreshing you're data.

example for setting cache false.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Comment: getJSON is jquery's shorthand for ajax method

Comment: is it by the way possible to disable cache with getJSON or not at all so gave to use $.ajax

Comment: look at my  post answer , hope it will help you